# no ssl certificate, google chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl

After the computer is unplugged, on the next start up chrome does not connect to google. Says the certificate is not valid and the ssl connection cannot be established. Same goes for facebook and other pages. After a while it just starts functioning. If the computer is just shut down there are no issues, this only happens if it has been unplugged from the power source. IE does the same, but the certificates can be installed and it establishes connection briefly.
Any ideas what could be the cause?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may need to check you Date and Time settings on your computer are correct. This will affect the certificates that are pre-installed in your computer if the date and time are incorrect. Hope this helps you..